# Can I import a branch from a Github repository in a Gitlab repository?

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I think one way is import entire repo from Github on Gitlab and after try to move a branch from this imported repository to my native gitlab repo.

Answer (score 4):

The simplest way would be to create a sandbox with two remotes, and push the branch you want to the second remote:

```
git clone <github_url>
cd <repo_name>
git remote add gitlab <gitlab_url>
git push gitlab <branch_name>
```